# Flutter 2 - Compilation error on getter: The return type of getter 'loading' is 'dynamic' which isn't a subtype > of the type 'bool'

Tags: flutter

After migrating to flutter 2, I'm having this error on the getter:

> The return type of getter 'loading' is 'dynamic' which isn't a subtype
> of the type 'bool' of its setter 'loading'.

```
class xxProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
    bool _loading = false;
    
    get loading => _loading;
    set loading(bool loading) {
      _loading = loading;
      notifyListeners();
    }
}
```

Any idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace

```
get loading => _loading;
```

with

```
bool get loading => _loading;
```

more info can be found here in dart docs: https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems